# How point cost of Unhealing disadvantage on only part of the body?

Tags: gurps-4e, gurps

I am creating a character with a cybernetic arm, which needs repair (and therefore qualifies for Unhealing (Total)[-30]), but it seems unfair to have the character gain 30 points for what is only a problem with part of their body.

**How does one point cost Unhealing (Total) on only part of a character's body?**

Comment: Is this arm supposed to be a prosthetic (i.e., it’s a replacement arm that isn’t otherwise special), or is it supposed to be better/faster/stronger than the old flesh arm (i.e., an upgrade rather than just a replacement)?

Comment: We haven't decided, but the arm is non functional without the enhancement either way.

Comment: Okay — you should probably pick one for the purpose of this question because the answer is likely significantly different. Then once you decide, if it’s the opposite, you can post a second question about the other. That will make for a clearer question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GURPS Ultra-Tech p. 207 covers how to build cybernetic body parts.  The short version is that you take the appropriate disadvantage (One Arm in this case) and then apply a Mitigator (B112) based on the limitations of the cybernetics

[According to Sean Punch](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=25239) Unhealing by itself would be a -90% Mitigator.  The usual combination for cybernetics given in Ultra-Tech is Unhealing, Electrical, and Monthly maintenance for -70%

Mitigator limitations are not subject to  the -80% limitation cap since that's not exploitable the way it would be with advantages.

One Arm (Mitigator, Unhealing, -90%) [-2]

One Arm (Mitigator, Unhealing, Electrical, Monthly Maintenance, -70%) [-6]

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way seems to be to base it on the rules for Damage Resistance with Partial coverage (pp B46-47). Damage Resistance on a single arm is bought at -40%.

However, we're limiting a *disadvantage* here. The easy way to do that is (-100-advantage limitation)%, which comes to -60%. So Unhealing (Total, 1 arm) would be -12 points.